# Rewrite rules for removing the `.html` file name extension

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have tried following command in the the .htaccess file to remove .html extension and put slash at the end. But it is not working. Can anyone suggest me what is going wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these rules in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```